# Select all users with specific MySql request PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm coding a feature in PHP, it's a search engine.

```html
<form action="result" method="POST">
  <select name="instrument" id="instrument">
    <option value="all">All instrument</option>
    <option value="1">Guitar</option>
    <option value="2">Bass</option>
    <option value="3">Battery</option>
    <option value="4">Singer</option>
  </select>
  <select name="theme" id="theme">
    <option value="all">All themes</option>
    <option value="1">Metal</option>
    <option value="2">Jazz</option>
    <option value="3">Rock</option>
    <option value="4">Blues</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="search" />
</form>
```

I already code this search engine like this and it works

```
<?php 


if(isset($_POST)) {

    $theme = $_POST['theme'];
    $instrument = $_POST['instrument'];


    $req_search = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM user,theme,instrument WHERE theme.theme_id = user.user_theme AND instrument.instrument_id = user.user_instrument AND theme_id =".$theme." AND instrument_id =".$instrument);

    if($req_search->rowCount()>0) {

    while($search = $req_search->fetch()) {

        ?>

        <p><?php echo $search['user_username']; ?></p>

    <?php 

    }

    $req_search->closeCursor();

    } else {
        echo "Users not found";
    }

}
```

?>

**You can find users who is matching with those options (without `All instrument` and `All themes`**.

Everything is stored into a MySql database.

However when I click on `All themes` and `All instrument`. I want to update my select request. Like if I select `All instrument` and `All themes` I want to display every users. Or if I select `All instrument` and `Metal`, I want to display all users listening to metal and playing whatever instrument.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I would advise making a conditional WHERE statement. Meaning if Not All is selected, you make the SQL with the WHERE statement. This will return all results.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct your query to be conditional depending on whether `$theme` and `$instrument` have values:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM user,theme,instrument 
    WHERE theme.theme_id = user.user_theme
    AND instrument.instrument_id = user.user_instrument".
    ($theme!="" ? " AND theme_id='$theme'" : "").
    ($instrument!="" ? " AND instrument_id='$instrument'" : "");

$req_search = $bdd->query($query);
```

That said, you should look into [PDO Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [Placeholders](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PDO-Positional-and-Named-Placeholders-P551.html), because all this would take is someone to fiddle around with the DOM to perform some MySQL Injection.